# How to center a row in a modal?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm using bootstrap 3, I can't center items inside, I inserted my code here but it doesn't look like the website.

```js
$('#modall').modal('show');
```

```css
  .fr-popup-btn-margin-left{
  margin-left:1.7vw !important;
}
.fr-title-popup-margin{
  margin-top:20px;
}
.fr-popup-btns{
  text-align:center;
}
.fr-popup-title{
  font-size:24px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #008cc0;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
}
.modal-fr-btn{
    border-radius: 40px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 80px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 800;
    padding: 0;
}
.dont{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size:10px;
}

.first-row-popup {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-right:0px;
  margin-left:0px;
  margin-bottom:10px;

}
@media (min-width: 992px){
    .pop2{
        width:25vw;
    }
        .pop1{
          width:30%;
    }
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
  
  <div class="modal fade" id="modall" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog pop2 modal-md">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <button type="button" class="close close-fr-popup" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <div class="fr-popup-title">
                <div class="modal-title">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="row nopadding">

                    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center flag-col">
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="close-fr-popup" href="">
                                <img class="img-circle flag" alt="English" src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" height="54"
                                    width="54">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="dont close-fr-popup col-xs-6" href="">English</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center flag-col">
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="close-fr-popup" href="">
                                <img class="img-circle flag" alt="English" src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" height="54"
                                    width="54">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="dont close-fr-popup col-xs-6" href="">English</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center flag-col">
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="close-fr-popup" href="">
                                <img class="img-circle flag" alt="English" src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" height="54"
                                    width="54">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="dont close-fr-popup col-xs-6" href="">English</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center flag-col">
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="close-fr-popup" href="">
                                <img class="img-circle flag" alt="English" src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" height="54"
                                    width="54">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="dont close-fr-popup col-xs-6" href="">English</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="row nopadding">

                    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center flag-col">
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="close-fr-popup" href="">
                                <img class="img-circle flag" alt="English" src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" height="54"
                                    width="54">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="dont close-fr-popup col-xs-6" href="">English</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center flag-col">
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="close-fr-popup" href="">
                                <img class="img-circle flag" alt="English" src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" height="54"
                                    width="54">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="dont close-fr-popup col-xs-6" href="">English</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center flag-col">
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="close-fr-popup" href="">
                                <img class="img-circle flag" alt="English" src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" height="54"
                                    width="54">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="dont close-fr-popup col-xs-6" href="">English</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center flag-col">
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="close-fr-popup" href="">
                                <img class="img-circle flag" alt="English" src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" height="54"
                                    width="54">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="dont close-fr-popup col-xs-6" href="">English</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Notice how on the website, the flags aren't in the middle of the modal, they are slightly to the left. I don't want to add padding or margin.

[image]

In addition to what I tried above, I also tried `text-center` the row and `text-align: center` and `margin: 0 auto`. Nothing works, seems like something is adding padding to the left more than the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest fix you can apply for this:

```
.flag-col > .row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```js
$('#modall').modal('show');
```

```css
.fr-popup-btn-margin-left{
  margin-left:1.7vw !important;
}
.fr-title-popup-margin{
  margin-top:20px;
}
.fr-popup-btns{
  text-align:center;
}
.fr-popup-title{
  font-size:24px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #008cc0;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
}
.modal-fr-btn{
    border-radius: 40px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 80px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 800;
    padding: 0;
}
.dont{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size:10px;
}

.first-row-popup {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-right:0px;
  margin-left:0px;
  margin-bottom:10px;

}
@media (min-width: 992px){
    .pop2{
        width:25vw;
    }
        .pop1{
          width:30%;
    }
}
.flag-col > .row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
  
  <div class="modal fade" id="modall" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog pop2 modal-md">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <button type="button" class="close close-fr-popup" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <div class="fr-popup-title">
                <div class="modal-title">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="row nopadding">

                    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center flag-col">
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="close-fr-popup" href="">
                                <img class="img-circle flag" alt="English" src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" height="54"
                                    width="54">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="dont close-fr-popup col-xs-6" href="">English</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center flag-col">
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="close-fr-popup" href="">
                                <img class="img-circle flag" alt="English" src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" height="54"
                                    width="54">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="dont close-fr-popup col-xs-6" href="">English</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center flag-col">
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="close-fr-popup" href="">
                                <img class="img-circle flag" alt="English" src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" height="54"
                                    width="54">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="dont close-fr-popup col-xs-6" href="">English</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center flag-col">
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="close-fr-popup" href="">
                                <img class="img-circle flag" alt="English" src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" height="54"
                                    width="54">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="dont close-fr-popup col-xs-6" href="">English</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="row nopadding">

                    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center flag-col">
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="close-fr-popup" href="">
                                <img class="img-circle flag" alt="English" src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" height="54"
                                    width="54">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="dont close-fr-popup col-xs-6" href="">English</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center flag-col">
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="close-fr-popup" href="">
                                <img class="img-circle flag" alt="English" src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" height="54"
                                    width="54">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="dont close-fr-popup col-xs-6" href="">English</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center flag-col">
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="close-fr-popup" href="">
                                <img class="img-circle flag" alt="English" src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" height="54"
                                    width="54">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="dont close-fr-popup col-xs-6" href="">English</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center flag-col">
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="close-fr-popup" href="">
                                <img class="img-circle flag" alt="English" src="https://i.imgur.com/ABwB1YD.png" height="54"
                                    width="54">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row nopadding">
                            <a class="dont close-fr-popup col-xs-6" href="">English</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Tried that, didn't solve it, check the website to see, I made the width of the modal bigger so you can see better.

Comment: You're right, just tested. Updated my answer with something that works. Cheers! Another possible fix is to apply `col-xs-offset-3` to each of your links, but that's more involved than the above CSS.

Comment: Thanks so much, I can accept your answer in 5 minutes, SO won't allow me before that, thanks again :)